# AssertText between an input value and stored variable text in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

Having trouble with returning the text from an attr node for the purpose of using in a AssertText Selenium IDE command.

Command: AssertText
Target: //input[@id='myInputTextBoxID']/@value
Value: ${myStoredSeleniumVal}

The result is [error] Element xpath=//input[@id='V1_I1_T5']/@value not found
I have tried using a literal for the value, and several variations of the xpath - this one however is confirmed to bring back the attribute node - but not the text from firebug command line $X(xpath)

Any help?
THanks

Answer (score 0):

Helps to read the documentation and not assume that an element can also be an attribute!

Change the command to assertAttribute, and it works!!